# Clear Table Without Deleting Index

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I run the following VBA it does what I need.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tmp_tbl_order_short"
```

I then repopulate the table but when I run a query against that data it is dog slow.  Reason is that the index is gone.

Can I recreate an index via VBA or is there another way of clearing the table without removing the index?

Comment: The index is gone? I dont know about DoCmd.RunSQL, but quidlines say, you should avoid it at any cost. So have you tried CurrentDb.Execute "Your query" instead? Let me know how it turns out!

Comment: When you "repopulate" the table are you using a make-table query (`SELECT ... INTO tmp_tbl_order_short FROM ...`)? If so, then you are not *repopulating* the table, you're *recreating* the table. In that case it's not the `DELETE` query that's causing the index to disappear, it's the `SELECT ... INTO`.

Comment: @GordThompson: "Recreate". Of course. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by 'index is gone'?? If field was indexed, then when you add new data, it will re-index. You are not deleting table and recreating it, which you can do, if needed, with following SQL statements that you can execute:

```
DROP TABLE tempTable;

CREATE TABLE tempTable(all fields)
```

and Follow by creating index:

```
CREATE INDEX myTempIndex  
ON tempTable (FieldToIndex)
```

In my opinion, something else is making your query go slower, perhaps wrong field indexed etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok ... my bad.  During development of this process the query that repopulated the table was a 'make table' query which was fine until I realized an index was required.  The original VBA sequence cleared the table and then I THOUGHT appended the new data.

So the 'DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tmp_tbl_order_short"' was not deleting the index, the make table query was.